# Error occured while integrating Codeigniter with Sentry 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, cartalyst-sentry

I simply followed the instruction of the following link but am getting this error while integrating Sentry 2 with Codeigniter 3.

Link: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#configuration

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>   Message: Class 'Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\CI\Sentry' not found
>   Filename: config/config.php
>   Line Number: 513
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\codeigniter2\application\config\config.php
>   Line: 513
>   Function: class_alias
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\codeigniter2\index.php
>   Line: 292
>   Function: require_once

Answer (score 2):

Try It

Add autoload.php to your Codeigniter’s index.php before require_once BASEPATH.’core/CodeIgniter.php’;

```
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

you must run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

first

Answer (score 0):

Hey in case someone is still looking for a solution try to implement as such - https://thephpx.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/setup-sentry-on-codeigniter-3-1/